# Async module returning promise [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to export the value with instrument variable. however data is returning as [object Promise] than object. How can I assign module variable with the final result rather than the promise object.

```
var instruments = { 
    data: async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            /// Respond after retrieving the data 
            resolve({result : "...." }
        );
    }
}

var symbols =   async () => {
    const res = await instruments.data();
    return res;
}

module.exports.instrument  =  symbols().then((data) => {
    console.log('data');
    return data; 
}).catch((e) => {
   console.log('error');
   return {}
});
```

Comment: ALL async functions return a promise - always.    That's what they do.  Your caller will have to use that promise to get access to the value with `.then()` or with `await`.  The moment, you hit an `await` inside an `async` function, it suspends execution of that function and immediately returns a promise back to the caller of the function.  Sometime later after the `await` is done and you finish executing the rest of the `async` function, then that promise that was previously returned will get resolved with the return value of the function.

Comment: FYI, there are probably a thousand questions like this here on stackoverflow so searching may turn up a bunch more for further help.  It is apparently common for people to not fully understand how an `async` function works and how `await` actually works with it so this is a really common misunderstanding.  `await` makes things appear synchronous within the function, but does not change anything to the outside world.  The outside world gets a promise back and still has to use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the value from the function.

Comment: @jfriend00 How can i use caller, I am using  simple call  with module variable only `console.log(Data.instrument)` it returns only promise. I tried with `.then()' as ` Data.instrument.then( lists => lists )', it is still returning promise return for some reason.

Comment: The caller HAS to use that promise.  Export runs synchronously and you cannot (in current versions of node.js) export an asynchronously retrieved value.  You simply cannot do it.  You will have to export the promise (as you are already doing) and the code that is importing that will have to take that promise and use `.then()` or `await` on it to get access to the value.  That's how asynchronous code works as of right now.

Comment: `var instrument =   Data.instrument().then((data) => {
       return data;
      
       }).catch((e) => {
          return {}
         }); `  I do, when I call and assign the return data, it become promise though.

Comment: The caller uses the promise result INSIDE the `.then()` handler.  That's where they use it.  This is how asynchronous programming works in Javascript.  You don't try to get the value out - you can't.  You can call a function from within the `.then()` handler and pass it the value if that feels better, but you MUST use the value from within the `.then()` handler.  So, stop trying to get the value outside.  It won't work.

Comment: @jfriend00, why can't we use value outside? can we assign the result into variable of object, instead of promise object? that was the main question ;P

Comment: Because the ONLY place you know WHEN the value is actually available is inside the `.then()` handler.  Remember an asynchronous operation finishes at some indeterminate time in the future and the whole point of the `.then()` handler is to tell you WHEN the asynchronous value is finally available.  So, whatever you're going to do with that value has to START inside the `.then()` handler by executing code there or calling a function from there.  Nowhere outside the `.then()` handler has any idea WHEN the value is actually there.

Comment: For now, you just need to accept this as a fact and move on to proper solutions.  You can write more synchronous looking code using `await` with promises, but the underlying concepts are the same and `await` won't help you at all with exporting a value.  All you can export here is the promise.  And, the caller will have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of the promise.

Comment: @jfriend00, alrighty, i am doing this way to bring the variable.... is that okay? 

`module.exports.instrument  =  symbols().then((data) => {
            module.exports.instrumentdata = data; 
        }).catch((e) => {
           return {}
        }); `

Comment: @Keyme What are you using the instrument variable for? (how are you using it in the code that requires the module?)

Comment: @richytong I am using module to store all the data, and when user uses new data, it can  delete loaded module and reload the module to store. Instrument is just name to store the list of objects.

Comment: I accept the answer of jfriend00 and DaneBrouwer which is basically states that  returning data from inside the then will not assign the value to instrument... Thanks all.

Comment: i'll post anyways for posterity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) cache. Here is a basic implementation

`cache.js`

```js
let data = {}

module.exports = {
  getData: () => {
    return data
  },
  setData: newData => {
    data = newData
    return
  },
}
```

No need for async here. I would separate this code with the code that retrieves data.

`fetchData.js`

```js
const cache = require('./cache')

const fetchData = () => {} // fetch data code here

fetchData().then(data => {
  cache.setData(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var instruments = { 
data:  () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        /// Respond after retrieving the data 
             resolve({result : "...." }); 

}
}

var symbols =   async () => {
    const res = await instruments.data();
    return res;
}

module.exports.instrument  =  symbols;
```

then import instrument method to call and then call

```
const instrument  = require("./filepath");

instrument().then((data) => {
    console.log('data');

    }).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e);
   });
```

Comment: When I do call with variable to store the data, it is returning the promise some reason. 
`var instrument =  Binary.instrument().then((data) => {
       return data;
      
       }).catch((e) => {
          return {}
         }); `

Comment: @Keyme returning `data` from`inside` the `then` will `not assign the value to instrument`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer how can I assign that return value into variable?

Comment: If you want to return inside than so you have to return promise instead of data

Comment: Anyway, I am assigning the return into new module name, is that okay? 

`module.exports.instrument  =  symbols().then((data) => {
            module.exports.instrumentdata = data; 
        }).catch((e) => {
           return {}
        }); `

Answer (score -2):

If your async function `instruments.data()` called, it'll `await` return `Promise`.
just append `await` at `return` for your expected result.

```
var instruments = { 
    data: async () => {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
             // Respond after retrieving the data 
             resolve({result : "...." }); 
        }
}
```

or remove `async`. it's same as above.

```
var instruments = { 
    data: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
             // Respond after retrieving the data 
             resolve({result : "...." }); 
        }
}
```

Comment: The function `symbols` already awaits the response for `instruments.data`.